# Internal CSS function is not working

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have this code sample for a `drop down list`. I want to change the Hovering color when I hover over the name `Our Softwares` (which is under the class `dropdown-toggle`)

Here's the code sample:

```
                   <li class="dropdown" >
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="color:white;" >Our Softwares<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Software 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Software 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Software 3</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

And here's the Internal CSS I used to achieve the above mentioned function:

```
.dropdown .dropdown-toggle a:hover{
            background-color: red; 
            color: blue;
        }
```

But it is not working. Can anyone please tell me what Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to put the `a` before the class `.dropdown-toggle` as the class is for the `a` rather than an element containing it.

I also added `!important` to the color because it's declared as white in the inline css (which takes priority).

```
.dropdown  a.dropdown-toggle:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: blue!important;
}
```

You can test it out here:

```css
.dropdown a.dropdown-toggle:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: blue!important;
}
```

```html
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="color:white;">Our Softwares<span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Software 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Software 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Software 3</a></li>

  </ul>
</li>
```